# jQuery mobile header iphone safari

Tags: iphone, jquery-mobile, header, mobile-safari

I am have a very strange issue with my mobile web site.

I am using jQuery Mobile on the site. It works well on other devices, but iPhone safari is not showing header correctly. Here is the screen in iPhone Safari -

[image: Safari Screen]

It should be like following -

[image: Android Screen]

Here is header code i am using -

```
<div data-role="header" data-theme="c" data-tap-toggle="false">

    <div style="height: 40px; border: 0px;" class="ui-header ui-bar-a">

        <a href='#' class='ui-btn-left' data-icon='arrow-l'
            data-direction="reverse"
            onclick="location.href='index.php#mainmenu'; return false;">Back</a>
        <div style="text-align: center;">
            <img src="images/mytechlogy_full_white_text_bigM.png"
                style="width: 200px; padding-top: 5px;" />
        </div>
        <a href="#" class='ui-btn-right' data-icon='home'
            data-iconpos="right"
            onclick="location.href='index.php#mainmenu'; return false;">Home</a>
    </div>

    <div
        style="height: 20px; background: #FF9933; vertial-align: middle; padding: 0px; border: 0px;">
        <span id="page-title"
            style="text-align: left; margin-top: 4px; padding-left: 5px;">My
            Profile</span>
    </div>

</div>
```

Please help me in this.

Answer (score 1):

adding data-position="fixed" in solved the problem.

```
<div data-role="header" data-theme="c"
        style="text-align: center; height: 60px;" data-tap-toggle="false" data-position="fixed">
```